# Newest Record from three tables grouped by supplier

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I need to create a list with records out of three tables (table 1/2/3) from by database (SQLServer). 
The Goal is, that the date of the newest delivery of each supplier is listed in ACCESS.
e.g.

- Supplier 1 | Date 1
- Supplier 1 | Date 2
- Supplier 1 | Date 3
- Supplier 2 | Date 1
- Supplier 2 | Date 2

will become

- Supplier 1 | Date 3
- Supplier 2 | Date 2

I was able to create the complete list, but can't find away to filter out the newest delivery dates. Here is my code so far:

```
stmt_frei_list = " SELECT MBS.PartID, MBS.Supplier, MBS.Freigabe, V.VerwendID, V.PartID, V.SupplierID, V.Date, " & _
                " SZ.SupplierID, SZ.Supplier " & _
                " FROM Table1 as MBS INNER JOIN Table2 as V ON MBS.PartID = V.PartID " & _
                " INNER JOIN Table3 AS SZ ON SZ.Supplier = MBS.Supplier AND V.SupplierID = SZ.SupplierID " & _
                " WHERE MBS.PartID = " & id & " " & _
                " ORDER BY V.Date DESC "
```

There where some hints in the forum, but I could not get it running. 
Do you have any advice? Thank you very much in advance.
- Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access, you can use:

```
stmt_frei_list = "SELECT MBS.Supplier, Max(V.Date) As NewestDate " & _
                 "FROM Table1 as MBS INNER JOIN Table2 as V ON MBS.PartID = V.PartID " & _
                 "INNER JOIN Table3 AS SZ ON SZ.Supplier = MBS.Supplier AND V.SupplierID = SZ.SupplierID " & _
                 "WHERE MBS.PartID = " & id & " " & _
                 "GROUP BY MBS.Supplier"
```

If *Null* values for Date exists:

```
stmt_frei_list = "SELECT MBS.Supplier, Max(Nz(V.Date, Date())) As NewestDate " & _
```

without *Nz*:

```
stmt_frei_list = "SELECT MBS.Supplier, Max(IIf(V.Date Is Null, Date(), V.Date)) As NewestDate " & _
```

Comment: Great Job! That did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I found an issue with the solution above. In some cases, there is no date available, but I need to list the supplier anyway. At the Moment, only suppliers with a valid date are listed. Any suggestions?

Comment: The Nz function is not recognized as an integrated function. So I tried to use iif instead, but it did not work properly. It still shows only the entries with a valid date: Max(IIF(V.Date Is Null, Null, V.Date)) as NewestDate

Comment: Try the second modification not using _Nz_.

Comment: Thanks for the Response. Unfortuneatly, Date() is also not a built-in function. But I made a work around based on your Initial query. In the first step, I ask for the data with no Null values and after that i load the rest of the data without asking for a date at all.

Answer (score 0):

you Can Achieve this In SQL Server

```
SELECT
        Supplier,Date
    (
        SELECT  Supplier,Date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Supplier ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
        FROM Table1 
    ) t
    WHERE t.rn = 1;
```